# user account control issue when running external exe in java

Tags: java, runtime, exe, external

I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run a external exe file in java. However there's a user account control window popped up, saying `"do you want to allow the following program form unknown publisher to make changes to this computer"`. How can I solve this issue only by using java?

Comment: Sounds like windows UAC not sure if u can control that from Java.

Comment: JNI or JNA comes to mind.

Comment: some application need administrator privilege .you can't simply avoid it.but you can change user account control setting to disable it.